# Apache on Lion Server with two IP addresses

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server, httpd.conf, osx-lion

I'm trying to run Apache and nginx on the same machine, on different IP addresses.

It's a Mac Mini with one ethernet card. I configured two eth network devices. I tried to change the apache configuration in /etc/apache2 to listen only on one IP, and most of it works. However, there is still an apache redirect from http:80 to https:443 on the second IP and I don't know where else to look. I changed all virtual hosts, virtual host global files and the httpd.conf including all default and __shadow files.

So I suppose it's not a problem of the SSL configuration, as I don't even want to get to the SSL part. It's the redirect from 80 to 443 which is not supposed to happen.

What else do I need to change to make apache listen on only one IP address and not change the protocol?

httpd.conf is too large. Important part:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
<IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
Listen 172.1.1.1:80
</IfDefine>
```

000_any_80__shadow.conf

```
<VirtualHost 172.1.1.1:80>
ServerName *
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access_log" combinedvhost
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCipherSuite "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
SSLProxyProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
DocumentRoot /var/empty

</VirtualHost>
```

0000_any_80_.conf.default

```
## Default Virtual Host Configuration

<VirtualHost 172.1.1.1:80 >
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/empty"
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /wiki/ default.html
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access_log" combinedvhost
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error_log"

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLEngine Off
    SSLCipherSuite "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
    SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/empty">
    Options All +MultiViews -ExecCGI -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
        DAV Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

sites/virtual_host_global.conf

```
Listen  172.1.1.1:443
NameVirtualHost 172.1.1.1:443
Listen  172.1.1.1:80
NameVirtualHost 172.1.1.1:80
```

apachectl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

Thanks!

Comment: Patrick, I think your going to need to post/link to all your configuration files for us to help you. Have you checked the ssl.conf file? All your vhosts?

Comment: The output of `apache2ctl -S` or `apachectl -S` will help.

Comment: Added the config files and output. Don't know if it helps though :(

Answer (score 0):

To make it stop listening on 443 comment out the "Listen 172.1.1.1:443" and the associated NameVirtualHost line. You should probably comment out the rewrite rule in 000_any_80__shadow.conf or just get rid or just exclude that file completely if you're not going to use it.

Odd thing, though, is that your `apachectl -S` command had no output. That should have shown those Virtual hosts. If you check the bottom of your main httpd.conf file, it should have a bunch of Include lines. Can you verify that it's even using all of those extra .conf files that you've posted?

Comment: Yes, all files are included properly. I don't want it to stop listening, I need the service on this IP. Just not on the second IP. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question